# What does 'delete mode 100644' mean in a git commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

I made a commit and I get:

```
229 files changed, 16 insertions(+), 22970 deletions(-)

delete mode 100644 Foo.file
.
.
.
delete mode 100644 Bar.file
```

FWIW I recently did some `git-worktree` stuff and created a new worktree but I don't think that has anything to do with this.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10104409/2820150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listing at the end of `git commit` here:

```
229 files changed, 16 insertions(+), 22970 deletions(-)

delete mode 100644 Foo.file
```

is the result of invoking `git diff --stat` on the then-current (now-previous) and now-current aka `HEAD` commit, which Git just built by writing out Git's index as a new tree and adding the appropriate metadata.

You should see the same output if you run `git diff HEAD@{1} HEAD`.  You can also use `git diff HEAD~1 HEAD` or similar.

As for why files `Foo.file`, `Bar.file`, etc., are *omitted* from the current commit when they were *present* in the previous commit: That is necessary because you told Git to remove those files from Git's index. Your `git worktree` experimentation should have had nothing to do with it since each added work-tree has its own separate index.

Comment: what's the 100644 for?

Answer (score 0):

100644 is a bit cryptic way of showing the file permissions, the number 100644 means that this is a regular file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).